# An updating display tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a bit of trouble on how to figure out how to make a display. I have two questions: Which widget should I use? and How can I actually make it do what I want to do? 
I'm still a beginner when it comes to Tkinter so it's confusing for me. I've tried searching online before posting this question but it only made me more confused. I would really appreciate it if someone would be willing to help. Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have so far.

```
#Imports Tkinter as tk

import Tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Phone Dial")


#def display:
#creates a display
#update display when a button is pressed
#continues to list numbers when button is pressed
    #ex. only 2 is displayed -> (Button "3" is pressed)-> displays 23
        #like a calculator display


#Dial buttons from #0-10
b=tk.Button(root,text="1",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=2,column=1)
b1=tk.Button(root,text="2",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=2,column=2)
b2=tk.Button(root,text="3",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=2,column=3)
b3=tk.Button(root,text="4",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=3,column=1)
b4=tk.Button(root,text="5",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=3,column=2)
b5=tk.Button(root,text="6",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=3,column=3)
b6=tk.Button(root,text="7",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=4,column=1)
b7=tk.Button(root,text="8",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=4,column=2)
b8=tk.Button(root,text="9",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=4,column=3)
b9=tk.Button(root,text="0",bd=5,width="5").grid(row=5,column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you're ready to do some research into how to build a Tkinter application (and you might look into `list`s and method chaining, too). I recommend [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).

Comment: You may wish to look at event driven programming.  Also you need to put buttons in a frame and the frame sits in root.

Comment: @user5823815 - You don't always need to use a `Frame`. It can be helpful to organize the app by grouping related items into `Frame`s, but you can make pretty complex apps by just adding widgets to the root object.

Comment: Thank you for this tips. It really helped :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thank you I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a little something about updating.**

- all you need to do is add `root.update()` at the end.
- all it does is just updates all your display.
- you would think that python would do something crazy to get it to update.

**Here is a website about updating.**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. I finally finished my code :)

Comment: Set it as the answer because other people might need to know about this `.update()`.

Comment: Useful answer. The link about updating dictionaries is not really relevant, though